# Camera turns black when I turn off flash light

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I use this code below to toggle on and off camera flash light

```
private void toggleFlash() {
    try {
        if(!flashOn) {
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        } else {
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
        }
        captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, handler);
        flashOn = !flashOn;
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It works, but the issue is this. At first when I open the camera (without flash light), I can see the image preview from the camera clear, but when I toggle on the flash and toggle it off, the preview becomes more darker than the initial time of opening the camera.

I'm still new to the camera API but I guess the issue is coming from here

```
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
```

But I don't know the proper code to use to make the camera not to be dark. Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going black because you're turning off auto-exposure, and I suspect the default manual exposure and sensitivity values are so low that the image is very underexposed.

You don't need to turn auto-exposure `OFF` when you turn off the flash. To control the flash manually, you do need to make sure AE is *not* set to `ON_AUTO_FLASH`, `ON_ALWAYS_FLASH`, or `ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE`, but that just means you can leave it as `ON` all the time, if you don't need automatic flash firing.

So just remove the bit about setting `CONTROL_AE_MODE` to `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF`

Answer (score 0):

Torch and flash are two different setting in camera2.
You can try and control flash with these setting.

On
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);

Off
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);